# experiencing crashes with joomla and mysql

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm currently moving a joomla website from a shared host to a dedicated one.

The problem I'm facing it's that I'm experiencing slow page loading and I think it has something to do with mysql. I tell you because sometimes (3 times since yesterday :S) mysql daemon goes down and I have to put it online again (log in /var/log/mysql/ doesn't report anything. Don't know why).

I turned on slow querys log and it reports this:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log ((Debian)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 140213 15:42:22
# User@Host: debian-sys-maint[debian-sys-maint] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 5.542592  Lock_time: 0.000729 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 643
SET timestamp=1392302542;
select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS`;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log ((Debian)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 140213 15:46:52
# User@Host: debian-sys-maint[debian-sys-maint] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.404442  Lock_time: 0.000656 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 643
SET timestamp=1392302812;
select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS`;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log ((Debian)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 140213 15:53:23
# User@Host: kool2B[kool2B] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.020636  Lock_time: 0.000340 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 4868
use kool2Bdb;
SET timestamp=1392303203;
SELECT i.id, i.catid, i.alias, i.modified, i.publish_down, c.alias AS categoryalias , c.name AS categoryname, i.title, i.introtext, i.fulltext
 FROM w0nmk_k2_items AS i
 INNER JOIN w0nmk_k2_categories c ON c.id = i.catid
 INNER JOIN w0nmk_k2_tags_xref tr ON tr.itemID = i.id
 AND tr.tagID IN (SELECT tagID FROM w0nmk_k2_tags_xref WHERE itemID = '5199')
 WHERE i.published = 1 AND c.published = 1
 AND (i.publish_down > CURDATE() OR i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
 AND i.id <> 5199  AND i.catid IN(149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,159,160,161,163,164,167,165,138,139,142,143,213)
 GROUP BY i.id
 LIMIT 0, 5;
# Time: 140213 15:56:34
# User@Host: kool2B[kool2B] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.612114  Lock_time: 0.000392 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 5865
SET timestamp=1392303394;
SELECT i.id, i.catid, i.alias, i.modified, i.publish_down, c.alias AS categoryalias , c.name AS categoryname, i.title, i.introtext, i.fulltext
 FROM w0nmk_k2_items AS i
 INNER JOIN w0nmk_k2_categories c ON c.id = i.catid
 INNER JOIN w0nmk_k2_tags_xref tr ON tr.itemID = i.id
 AND tr.tagID IN (SELECT tagID FROM w0nmk_k2_tags_xref WHERE itemID = '5275')
 WHERE i.published = 1 AND c.published = 1
 AND (i.publish_down > CURDATE() OR i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
 AND i.id <> 5275  AND i.catid IN(149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,159,160,161,163,164,167,165,138,139,142,143,213)
 GROUP BY i.id
 LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Do you think it's normal to have this times with this server?

Atom 1.6 GHz+ with 2 GB of RAM

Here's my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

Hope someone can give me a hand with this. Thanks.

Comment: If I was you I'd start off by fixing logging.  That is what tells you what's wrong with MySQL.  Anything else is a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've finally found that there was a component installed in joomla which had a security issue and a hacker used it to kill Apache. So there weren't any problems with mysql.

I've found it looking at apache logs. Well, thanks anyway!!

Regards